# Unable to connect to Apache MINA sshd server

Tags: sftp, sshd, apache-sshd

I'm trying to setup a sftp server with Apache MINA sshd. But I'm getting `subsystem request failed on channel 0` while trying to connect to the server.

```
sftp -P 22 john@localhost                                                                                                                                                            
Password authentication
(john@localhost) Password:
subsystem request failed on channel 0
Connection closed
```

I was following [this document](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/sshd-2.10.0/docs/server-setup.md). But I'm not sure whether I'm missing any essential parts here.

Following is the code I'm using at the moment with mina-sshd v2.10.0.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(22);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Paths.get("hostkey.ser")));

        sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory("/bin/sh", "-i", "-l"));
        sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());

        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new MyPasswordAuthenticator());

        try {
            System.err.println("Starting SSHD on port 22");
            sshd.start();
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            System.err.println("Exiting after a very (very very) long time");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is caused by the server not allowing SFTP. If you check [the SFTP docs for NIMA](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/sftp.md#server-side-sftp), you can see that you can enable the SFTP subsystem like this:

```java
SftpSubsystemFactory factory = new SftpSubsystemFactory.Builder()
    //...
    .build();
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(factory));
```

For further diagnosing, you could try creating a custom `SftpEventListener` and registering it with `factory.addSftpEventListener` or similar,